# Is Spring Framework 4.2.5 compatible with Oracle WebLogic 12.1.3?

Tags: java, spring, weblogic, weblogic12c

I know that Oracle WebLogic 12.1.3 officially supports verion of Spring Framework 4.0.x .

But, It seems that 4.0.x stream of Spring 
Framework will not be maintained in the future.

Then, I'm considering to work with 4.2.x of Spring.

Is there someone working on the same situation?

Spring Framework 4.2.x on Oracle WebLogic 12.1.3.

I'm wondering it works or not.
Please let me know your situation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We use Spring 4.2.0 on WebLogic 12.1.3 running on Linux. I had not seen any issues. However, I also do not know of any official support statement for this situation.

Answer (score 1):

From [Official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/NOTES/whatsnew.htm#NOTES381) is only supported:

The WebLogic Server/Spring integration features in WebLogic Server 12.1.3 support Spring Framework versions 3.0.x, 3.1.x, and **4.0.x**. (Note that Spring Framework version 3.2.x is not supported.)

This doesn't mean that won't work 4.2.5

Comment: thanks! don't you know any serious problem with that combination?